# wkhtmltopdf error: specified in incorrect location

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

This is a part of my shell script, where ${1} is 'input.html' and ${2} is 'output.pdf':

```
wkhtmltopdf "${1}" "${2}" --page-size letter --dpi 150 --margin-top 0.2in --margin-bottom 0.2in --margin-left 0.2in --margin-right 0.2in
```

When I ran the above, I got the following error:

```
--page-size specified in incorrect location
```

My wkhtmltopdf version:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version

wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 final
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed it to:

```
wkhtmltopdf --page-size letter --dpi 150 --margin-top 0.2in --margin-bottom 0.2in --margin-left 0.2in --margin-right 0.2in "${1}" "${2}"
```

and it worked.